# Two buttons, one remains visited till other is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a set of buttons. I need the button that is clicked to remain highlighted after it has been clicked. When another button is clicked, I need the last highlighted button to go back to its original state, and for the newly clicked button to now be highlighted and so on.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#button1 {
width: 100px;
height: 50px;
float: left;
margin-right: 3px;
background-color: red;
}
#button2 {
width: 100px;
height: 50px;
float: left;
background-color: red;
}
#button1:hover {
background-color: yellow;
}
#button2:hover {
background-color: yellow;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="button1"></div>
<div id="button2"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You'll need javascript to accomplish this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple bit of code, and its really simple, just native javscript, but if you check the fiddle below you can see it working

http://jsfiddle.net/y8rbncwj/

```
var toggle = function (e, old) {
   e.className = "selected";
   document.getElementById(old).className="";
```

};

Not knowing what exactly your trying to do how many buttons you have, this will toggle two buttons, click first it turns blue, click second first goes back to red, button clicked turns blue and so on.

You could do this with css and no java-script using radio buttons, since by nature they work in groups and can be toggled, to do that you would style the labels like a button with css, and hide the actual toggle behind it.

Comment: +1 for the radio buttons idea. You can make style those to look cool, while still keeping their choose-one functionality.

Comment: All together there are 5 buttons, I have just started learning javascript and don't know the syntax yet, so I'll try the radio button idea.

Comment: For sure. The radio button option is the best one. If you google around their are lots of pages that tell you how you can style them. Since they work as a group, select one only, they are perfect for your case needs. If you have problem come back here and we can help.

Comment: Do I win the Question?

Answer (score 1):

You should look into JavaScript to accomplish this.  I personally use jQuery, but simple JavaScript will work just fine for this scenario.  W3Schools provides a nice intro to integrating it, [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_whereto.asp).

For your specific scenario, you will want to use something like this:

```
document.getElementById('button1').onclick = function() {
   // Change button1 CSS here
}​;​
```

Additionally, you would want to add to this to accommodate for `#button2` and the other rules that you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

See the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/occm1twj/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="divParent1" class="parentDiv">
    Group 1
    <div id="child1" class="childDiv">
        Child 1
    </div>

    <div id="child2" class="childDiv">
        Child 2
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.parentDiv{
 border:1px solid black;
 padding:10px;
 width: 80px; 
 margin:5px;  
 display:relative;
}
.childDiv{
  border:1px solid blue;
  height: 50px;   
  margin:10px;
}
.parentDiv{
 border:1px solid black;
 padding:10px;
 width: 80px; 
 margin:5px;  
 display:relative;
}
.childDiv{
  border:1px solid blue;
  height: 50px;   
  margin:10px;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$('.childDiv').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().find('.childDiv').css('background-color','#ffffff');
    $(this).css('background-color','#ff0000');
});
```

Try it..

Answer (score 0):

I created a generic class `.button` and the relevant javascript function to achieve this. It will toggle multiple buttons, as long as they all have the same class `.button`:

CSS:

```
.button {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 3px;
    background-color: red;
}

.button:hover,
.button.selected {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

JS (with jQuery):

```
var button = $('.button');

button.on('click', function(){
    button.removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="button1" class="button"></div>
<div id="button2" class="button"></div>
<div id="button3" class="button"></div>
<div id="button4" class="button"></div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/oeegLosw/